# html: accessing options later in page

Tags: php, html, html-select

I'm new to html/php and I can't find the correct terminology to make google show me what I think is fairly simple.

I want to be able to take the selected option from form1 to list options in form2.
I then want to use the selected options from form1 and form2 in form3, but when I select option2 I lose the original choice. I have put a diagram here to help explain: http://imgur.com/c2Tx88O

I am probably doing this completely wrong. Advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form name='form1' action='./results.php'>
    <b>Data Origin:</b><br>
    <input type="radio" name="origin" value="SEQ" onclick=submit() selected >Barcode Sequencing
    <input type="radio" name="origin" value="MIC" onclick=submit() >Microscopy
</form>

<form name='form2' action='./results.php'>
    <b>Select a Site:</b><br>
    <?php
        foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
                $$key = $value;
                $origin = $value;
        }

        $sites = glob("analyses/$origin/*");

        foreach ($sites as $site){
            $site = preg_replace("/analyses\/$origin\//i", '', $site);
             print "<input name=\"site\" type=\"radio\" value=\"$site\"  onclick=\"submit()\">$site\n";

        }
    ?>
</form>

<?php
    foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
        $$key = $value;
        $site_code = $value;
        print "<b>site: $site_code</b>";

        $arr = array('phylum', 'class', 'order', 'family', 'genus', 'species');
        print "<br><select id='setit' name='url'>
        <option value=\"\">Choose Taxonomy level...</option>";

        foreach ($arr as $value){
            print "<option value='analyses//$site_code/$value.html'>$value</option>\n";
        }
        print "<input type='button' value='go' onclick=\"window.open(setit.options[setit.selectedIndex].value)\">";

    }
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic chained select box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737113/dynamic-chained-select-box)

Comment: Thanks for the link, they weren't anywhere near the terms I was searching. As a guy who doesn't know anything about ajax, is that absolutely necessary? Would I need to set up anything before implementing it? and I see from wikipedia that you need javascript enabled and I know from experience that our computers have it disabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To carry over info from the first form to the second, use this

```
<input type="hidden" name="origin" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['origin'])) echo $_GET['origin']; ?>" />
```

you can place it right after "Select a Site", like this

```
<form name='form2' action='./results.php'>
    <b>Select a Site:</b><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="origin" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['origin'])) echo $_GET['origin']; ?>" />
```

Also instead of doing all this to get `$origin`.

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
    $$key = $value;
    $origin = $value;
}
```

You may simply call this

```
$origin = $_GET['origin'];
```

but you have to check if it is set first, like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['origin']){
     $origin = $_GET['origin'];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working now. I really appreciate the help, especially as it's 10pm and now I can go home...

Answer (score 0):

Each time you submit a form, it refreshes the page and you lose data from any previous request.  To get around this you need to use a persistent storing method, like a session, to store and access data from a previous request.

Example: (this would be in results.php script somewhere)

```
session_start(); // This needs to be at the start of your script

$_SESSION['form1'] = $_POST['form1']; // Put the result of form one in here
// etc...
```

In your script with the form you'll need to call `session_start()` again, and then you can access previous data in the `$_SESSION` array.